# Unable to connect to myslq docker container on jenkins pipeline

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to connect to mysql docker container that i created using docker compose.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.12
    ports:
      - "6033:3306"
    command: --sql_mode="" --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --transaction-isolation=READ-UNCOMMITTED
    restart: always
    container_name: docker-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: transaction_summary
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

then in the pipeline script i run the .gradlew test command to run the test. However, it fails and complains about not being able to connect to the database.
Jenkins label used is Ubuntu-18.
My url looks like this in the application.

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:6033/transaction_summary
```

When i run it on my laptop, it runs fine. But it is failing on jenkins.
I added docker ps in the jenkins script to makee sure the container is running. and it is running giving me the following details:

```
197fbf0c793a   mysql:5.7.12  "docker-entrypoint.s…"  0.0.0.0:6033->3306/tcp  docker-mysql
```

I've tried 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.2 instead of localhost. and it still complains.

Answer (score 0):

May be try image name, i.e. `mysql`
url could look like `jdbc:mysql://mysql:6033/transaction_summary`